# How to get Child Components from ViewContainerRef - Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-dynamic-components

I added dynamic components (`ChildComponent.ts`) inside viewContainerRef. I able to get child count from viewContainerRef like this `viewContainerRef.length` if i use index to get Child Component (`viewContainerRef.get(0)`) it's return `ViewRef` But i need child component how to do this.

Example :

```
@ViewChild("cards_holder", { read: ViewContainerRef }) cards_holder: ViewContainerRef;

 const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory( SimpleCardComponent);
const componentRef = this.cards_holder.createComponent(componentFactory);

for (let index = 0; index < this.cards_holder.length; index++) {
    console.log(this.cards_holder.get(index)) //It's Return ViewRef but i need SimpleCardComponent
}
```

Thank you.
Sabish.M

Answer (score 0):

Since [createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent) return component refernce you can access SimpleCardComponent instance like this:

```
const componentRef = this.cards_holder.createComponent(componentFactory);
const compInstance = <SimpleCardComponent>componentRef.instance;
```

Comment: I hope you are tamil. I am from Tirunelveli.  Is possible get ComponentRef from ViewContinerRef after create Componenet.

Comment: createComponent method available in viewContainerRef  class only, But i dont think it's possible to get the component instance from ViewRef

Comment: @Sabish.M can't you store them manually? something like: `cards_holder.children = []; cards_holder.children.push(componentRef)`? so you don't loose the reference after creation.

Comment: I know this. I just asking get componenetRef without store the component reference anywhere .